# Inefficient Oracle Query, Pivot Alternative

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have data from an xml file pulled into an oracle database. The field MEAS_TYPE_NAME includes all of the metrics I need so I have to unpack them. I'm using Pivot but this seems to be an inefficient query and takes too long.

Has anyone done something like this before? Is there a better way?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    BEGIN_TIME,
    END_TIME,
    LOCAL_DN,
    USER_LABEL,
    SW_VERSION,
    MEAS_TYPE_NAME,
    P,
    R,
    MEAS_INFO_ID
  FROM ETL.ENM_STATS_DATA_RAW@RDW_P20.WORLD
  where BEGIN_TIME >= TRUNC(sysdate)-7
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(R)FOR MEAS_TYPE_NAME IN (
    'VS.MM.AttAttach.E', 'VS.MM.SuccPsPaging.E', 'VS.MM.AttPsPaging.E',
    'VS.MM.UnsuccAttach.E', 'VS.MM.UnsuccServiceReq.E', 'VS.MM.AttServiceReq.E',
    'VS.MM.NbrHomeSub.E', 'VS.MM.EpsAttachFail.8.E', 'VS.MM.EpsAttachFail.11.E',
    'VS.MM.EpsAttachFail.14.E', 'VS.MM.EpsAttachFail.15.E', 'VS.SM.NbrActDefaultBearer.E',
    'VS.MM.NbrActAttachedSub.E'
  )
)
ORDER BY LOCAL_DN
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the Pivot that is taking a long time to execute and not the `SELECT DISTINCT ...` statement? if you were to run that statement and get ALL the rows (not just the first subset like most development tools do) does that run relatively quickly?

Comment: There's a database link, so the issue may be in data transfer. You need to check query plan to find the problematic place